# Tracking Admob fill rate in Ionic 2 app

Tags: ionic2, admob

I am using the floatinghotpot/cordova-admob-pro plugin to display interstitial ads in my ionic v2 mobile app.

The app functions in such a way that an interstitial ad is displayed after the user completes action. The app is working fine and I have been getting some feedback from my users saying that they don't always see the ad displayed when they complete the action.

Is there a way that I can track the fill rate that I'm getting?

Comment: this is normal that admob won't send ads always, only if the ad is availbale

Comment: I'm assuming using multiple ad sources with mediation will help to increase the fill rate @rashidnk ?

Comment: ofcourse, mediation will increase fill rate,